# Submit To Same PHP Page Via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have written the following code and i'm looking for a little help in regards to submitting an form to the same PHP file , but via JavaScript.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['go'])) {
    header('location: index.php');
}
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function gogo() {
                document.form1.submit();
            }
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" name="form1" id="form1" action="example.php" />
            <input type="button" value="go" name="go" id="go" onclick="gogo();"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This isn't working. Can you suggest me where i'm going wrong here?

Comment: remove action attribute from form. and replace `onclick="this.form.sumit()"`

Comment: Remove all Javascript, change the input type to submit, and you're probably okay :)

Comment: But i need to do it from a javascript code. Since i'm looking for validation via javascript. Only if the controls are valid i'm looking to submit manually via javascript.

Comment: @RohanKhude thats not working either.

Comment: If it is form validation you are after, you should use the `onsubmit=""` attribute of a form.

Comment: Or, you could add a `<input type="hidden" name="go" value="" />` to the form.

Comment: @DaanMeijer , but if i'm submitting to same page then onsubmit will allow the form to be submitted before any validation. I'm aware of the return method for validation. But i don't think that will work either.

Comment: Your question is about submission but you are disregarding all the answer because you want to know about validation... So what is?

Comment: @nerdlyist my question is manual submission of form via javascript , which is not working here. I'm familiar with jQuery and return method. But they are not suitable for me thats why im asking this question. Can you think of a way to make this work without modifying problem definition?

Comment: @user7374170 is there a reason you want to use JS. You could just as easily use JS to stop an input validate and if passes submit.

Comment: @nerdlyist this is just a sample code i've written to make you help understand my problem. I've got like 10 fields in my code that need to be manually validated via javascript ( no html validations) So only if all these fields are valid , only then i want to submit the form manually via javascript. :) The problem with onsubmit="return gogo();" is that it will submit the form irrespective of validation. ( by submit i mean if(isset($_POST['go'])) will get triggered and execute its code )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that because you are using javascript to submit the form, the "go"-input doesn't get activated. The obvious (and very clean) solution would be to strip all javascript:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['go'])) {
    header('location: index.php');
}
?>

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="example.php" />
            <input type="submit" value="go" name="go" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, if you want to use form validation in javascript, you should probably do something like:

```
<script>
    function validateForm() {
        if(true/*check here*/) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
</script>
<form onsubmit="return validateForm();">
     ...
</form>
```

If you are (for whatever reason) really really sure you want to use the javascript submission as requested in your post, you just need to add a hidden input with the name go:

```
<form ...>
    <input type="hidden" name="go" value="" />
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: This isn't my actual code. I've submitted this as a dummy to see how can i first validate via javascript and then manually submit via js again. I don't need form to get submitted automatically.

Comment: the problem with the return method is that the if(isset($_POST['go'])) will detect and automatically submit & execute the code followed , irrespective of whether javascript returns true or false.

Comment: Your comment doesn't really make any sense (at least to me).There is a chance proper formatting would change that :) Then again, it might not.

Comment: Simply put , i just want to know whether the code i've written above can be made to work? Since most of its part is correct. :) I greatly appreciate your assistance. :D

Comment: The last part of my answer illustrates how to "just fix" your code. At least, according to my understanding of what you want to accomplish with it. If it doesn't, you'll have to provide more information about the incorrect behaviour you observe, as well as the behaviour you expect.

Comment: I'm really unsure how that can help me. But i have pasted my original code here [ http://pastebin.com/GkXFrDmE ] so if possible take a look. It has 2 files. register.php and validate.js. I'm looking for validateForm() function to submit the form upon all control validation is successful. Excuse me for my bad code , :)

Comment: I've updated them , but still the data gets posted to PHP even if validations fail. :(

Comment: Any messages in your javascript console?

Comment: Actually that last comment really helped me out. There was an issue with form name that created an error in fetching the radio button value. I'm not sure how it worked but it worked. Thanks mate.

Comment: If my answer helped you reach a solution, please mark it as accepted for future reference :)

Comment: Yes , surely i will. But i was wondering if there is any modification necessary to the answer so that the other people in same doubt may get proper idea as to what was problem. Once again thanks mate. My head is going bonkers due to continuous 6 hrs of coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
document.getElementById("form1").submit();
```

Comment: Nope, it isn't working. Should the $_POST contain form name or button name? i'm confused. Since button may not have a submit event.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function gogo() {
                document.form1.submit();
            }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" name="form1" id="form1" action="" />
            <input type="submit" value="go" name="go" id="go" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The gogo() function is never called here. And even if it were called via onclick="gogo();" , the following code will get executed as well irrespective of what gogo() does.

Answer (score -1):

use JQuery instead

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#Go").click(function () {
            var data = $("#form1").serialize();

            $.ajax({

                type:"POST",
                data:data,
                url:"example.php", //page where you want to submit the form
                success:function (data) {
                    // response from the server in browsers console
                    console.log(data)
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

make sure to change `<input type="submit" value="go" name="go" />`

to `<button id="Go" name="Go">Go</button>`

Comment: So there is no way of doing this via plain old javascript?

Comment: well this is better way if you want to submit your form to the same page

Comment: I don't really want to use ajax or jquery to do this simple task if possible. If it isn't then i won't have an choice but to switch to ajax.

Comment: did you try document.getElementById("form1").submit(); ?

Comment: Yup, as mentioned by one of the posts, i did try it. But sadly id doesn't work :(

Comment: it will submit to form to whatever page you mentioned on action tag

Comment: you can remove action tag if you want to submit form on same page

Comment: Still , it doesn't work :( I've tried a lot of it. Here's my actually messy code.http://pastebin.com/GkXFrDmE